# Effective Interest Rate Interpretation

Tags: interest-rate, interest, compound-interest

Assume a $1,000 loan for 24 months, with monthly interest rate 2.5%, and monthly payments ($55.91 as calculated by any online tool, e.g. [here](http://www.calculator.net/payment-calculator.html?ctype=fixterm&cloanamount=1000&cloanterm=2&cmonthlypay=1000&cinterestrate=30&printit=0&x=94&y=17)).

This will give us annual interest rate (air) of 30%, and effective interest rate 34,4889%, calculated as `eir = (1 + air/n)^n - 1`.

Is there any intuitive interpretation of 34.4889%? I have hard time understanding how to interpret this number as payments are coincident with interest rate calculation and in fact there is no compounding (interest calculated from interest) at all.

[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate) on effective interest rate:

> The effective interest rate is calculated as if compounded annually.

[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest) on compound interest:

> Compound interest is interest added to the principal of a deposit or
>   loan so that the added interest also earns interest from then on. This
>   addition of interest to the principal is called compounding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effective annual interest rate is the amount by which your loan will increase in a year if you don't make any payments.  If you don't make any loan payments in the first 12 months, then your loan amount will be `$1000*(1+0.025)^12 = $1344.89` which is 34.489% higher than your original loan amount.

Another way to think of it: if you had a loan that compounded annually at a rate of 34.489% and didn't pay it for a year, then the loan amount after one year will be `$1000*(1+0.34489) = $1344.89`, the same amount as above.

Answer (score 1):

R = I ^ P

1.80872594958 = 1.025 ^ 24

I = R ^ (1/P)

1.34488882425 = 1.80872594958 ^ (1/2)

2.5% per month = 34.5% per year